# How do I get wolfram to solve this problem?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I am trying to check some answers and can't seem to get wolfram to work properly.

I type in the following command :

integrate x.sin(x) dx

and it doesn't  provide any solution it just says "visual representation of the integral" and then gives nothing else.

I am trying to check a different problem but can't get it work. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by the period?  are you trying to get multiplication of x by $\sin(x)$?

Comment: integrate [ x * sin x, x]

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x\sin{x}

Comment: @barakmanos, bad link.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Copy the full link into your browser (do not click it here).

Answer (score 2):

Try typing the following :

> integrate [x * sin x, x]

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

$$\tt integrate(x\ sin(x) )$$

or

$$\tt integrate(x\sin(x),x)$$

See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28x+sin%28x%29+%29